# Ruby - getting uninterrupted range/-s from an array

Tags: ruby, while-loop, range

I have an `array = [1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

And I need to extract uninterrupted ranges, so `[1, 2, 3]` and `[6, 7, 8, 9]` in this case.

Please share your ideas for this, but also, please - fix my while loop as well. Learning is my priority nr 1.

My primary try to get at least one range was:

```
$sequence = []

while array.length > 0 do
    p @compare1 = array.index(0)
    p @compare2 = array.index(1)
    if @compare1 + 1 == @compare2
        $sequence << @compare1 
  end
    array = array[1..-1] 
end
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: hint: `array.chunk_while`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice solution:

```
array.chunk_while { |i, j| i + 1 == j }.select { |range| range.size > 1 }
 => [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

In your code the problem is that you are asking for the index of values 0 (and you don't have 0s) and 1, not the value at the positions 0 and 1. This is the first issue I note. You could do

```
compare1 = array[0]
compare2 = array[1]
```